# Timer in MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, timer, mips

I am implementing a game in MIPS assembly using MARS. I would like to implement some sort of timer that begins at 60 seconds and runs until it is 0. Every time a certain action is executed I would like to add additional time to the clock. Also, I would like to print the time remaining. Is it possible to do something like this, if so, how could I go about doing it?
Thanks

EDIT:

```html
.text
li $v0,30        
syscall

move $t1, $v0


li $v0,30          
syscall
move $t0, $v0

sub    $t2, $t1, $t0


li  $v0, 1
syscall
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly but the output I get is 213148934.

Comment: Yes it's possible. MARS offers system calls for getting the time and delaying for a given amount. If you need more help ask more specific question.

Comment: I see a syscall function 30 for system time. Could you give me a little insight on how this works?

Comment: `$a0` = low 32 bits, `$a1` = high 32 bits, milliseconds since 1 January 1970.

Comment: What does something like this do? li $v0,30

Comment: If you don't know that you are going to have problems ... `li` loads an immediate value into the given register, so that loads `30` into `$v0` (system calls expect the function number in that register).

Comment: Could I perform that syscall at the beginning and end of my program and subtract the values to get the elapsed time?

Comment: I edited my post to include the code I just put together.

Comment: I thought I was quite clear about where the result is going to be. Hint: `$a0` and `$a1`.

Comment: So, I should move the values from $a0 into another location, and subtract those?

Comment: Yes, you need to save `$a0` and `$a1` from the first call and use those in 64 bit subtraction (using 32 bit only you might get negative result due to wraparound).